# How to set value to specific tablecell Index in tableview JavaFx?

Tags: uitableview, tableview, javafx-8

I tried to set value in specific column index (cell), how to do this in javafx, I tried many methods to do that but every time my trial fail

```
//First try
productName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory(product.getCode()));

//Second try
name.setCellValueFactory(c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getTestBedName()));

//Thrid try
productCode.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Product, String>, 
ObservableValue<String>>()
{
    @Override public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Product,                                 
    {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getCode());
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are trying. So that someone can direct where you are going wrong.

Comment: I need to set value in specific column cell in tableview, like first column first cell, fill column cells one by one, some thing like in java swing "table.setValueAt(data, 0, 0);" so that I able to access the cell index and set some value on it

Comment: I think you came from a different environment(Swing) and trying to apply the same principles in JavaFX. I believe things work differently from JavaFX to Swing (I have no experience in Swing). But it would be helpful to you to build your JavaFX knowledge by first understanding its basic controls/concepts. May be this [TableView tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) can be a good starting point to you..

Comment: Thanks very much brother, Finally when I learn all javafx basics in this tutorial (I have some little) can I do this?

Comment: I complete reading the TableView chapter in the website now, and thanks for this knowledge, most tutorial add row to table using ObservableList, Can I find any method to add directly to TableColumn cell? thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot set data directly to specific row/column index table cell. GridPane will allow you to set data in that manner. TableView data should be controlled through data list.

Comment: Depending on the design of your `Product` class, you may actually be able to return a property object. If this does not work, neither updating the table by setting the property in a `Product` object nor setting a value given a row index and a `TableColumn` will work. `new PropertyValueFactory(product.getCode())` is almost certainly wrong. `new PropertyValueFactory("code")` may work, but depending on the design of your `Product` class setting the property won't do the trick. In this case and with the second attempt calling `table.refresh()` would be necessary after modifying an item...

Comment: Ok thanks brother, I'll try that

Comment: @SaiDandem can I ask you question?

Comment: @FaroukFarag yes you can :)

Comment: I have similar problem (not exactly the same in coding but the same concept) like this can you provide solution to this problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598826/event-on-combox-which-inside-tableview-cell-javafx

Comment: @SaiDandem can provide solution for the question in the above comment ?

Answer (score 0):

We will post our TableView that is populated from a Derby Database
We use a Model View Controller Pattern. So we could update one column in a selected row
OR we could pass a static variable from another controller that just inserts the value in the column only issue here is you need to know the row id

```
    TableData.add(new CBModel(rs.getString("ID"),rs.getString("sortDate")
    ,rs.getString("txMonth"),rs.getString("txYear"),rs.getString("txType"),rs.getString("txAmount")
    ,rs.getString("ckNum"),rs.getString("txDesc"),rs.getString("txBalance")));

    }
    PropertyValueFactory<CBModel, String> IDCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID");
    colID.setCellValueFactory(IDCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<CBModel, String> DateCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("sortDate");
    colTxDate.setCellValueFactory(DateCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<CBModel, String> TypeCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("txType");
    colTxType.setCellValueFactory(TypeCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<CBModel, String> AmountCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("txAmount");
    colTxAmount.setCellValueFactory(AmountCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<CBModel, String> CKNumCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("ckNum");
    colCKNum.setCellValueFactory(CKNumCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<CBModel, String> DescCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("txDesc");
    colTxDesc.setCellValueFactory(DescCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<CBModel, String> BalanceCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("txBalance");
    colTxBalance.setCellValueFactory(BalanceCellValueFactory);
    // ================================================================
    // colTxDate are the ID's for the tableview columns
    // sortDate  are the Column Names for the Database TABLE CDBalance
    // ================================================================
    colTxDate.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
    colCKNum.setStyle("-fx-alignment:CENTER;");
    colTxType.setStyle("-fx-alignment:CENTER;");
    colTxAmount.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER-RIGHT;");
    colTxBalance.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER-RIGHT;");
    //Collections.sort(TableData, (p1, p2)-> p2.getSortDate().compareToIgnoreCase(p1.getSortDate()));
    Collections.sort(TableData, (p2, p1)-> p1.getID().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getID()));
    // Line of Code above Sorts Database Columns based on VARIABLE in CBModel
    // Change p2,p1 to sort Ascending or Descending
    if(TableData.size() < 15) {// Format TableView to display Vertical ScrollBar
        table.setPrefWidth(926);
    }else {
        table.setPrefWidth(945);
    }   table.setItems(TableData);
    stmnt.close();  
}
```